# Text/Html JTextPane not rendering properly when pasting formatted text

Tags: java, jtextpane

I'm using a JTextPane with content type of text/html, but whenever I copy a formatted text from MS Word and pastes it on the textpane it doesn't get formatted or displays properly.
Some of the tags are being displayed like boxes.

I wanted to attach an image but I couldn't cos my reputation isn't up to 10 yet.

Please help me with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a common mistake. You need to set :

```
((HTMLDocument)myJTextPane.getDocument()).setPreservesUnknownTags(false);
//considering that you already equipped yout JTextPane with an HTMLDocument.
//Note that HTMLEditorKit automatically installs one.
```

I believe that's enough to fix your issue.

Comment: On what component exactly am I supposed to call this method?

Comment: If the content type of your JTextPane really is text/html, you should have an HTMLDocument. So you should call : ((HTMLDocument)myJTextPane.getDocument()).setPreserveUnknownTags(false);

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Java doesn't render all the tags but it does look a lot better than before. Oracle should provide further enhancement